# Need to retrieve input names from dynamic form inputs. The names of the input comes from the database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Okay, so I have got this form with pairs of fields... One is select, and the other is number input. If the select value is not null, the number input appears beside it... After submitting, I need to retrieve the name of the select menu, It's value And the value of the number input besides it...

The whole thing is getting impossible for me as the names of all these fields are being fetched from SQL.

Here's the image of the page I'm making:
[Preview Of My Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJhVB.jpg)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Qv1Hr8tSIj95qBb98vCV1kftdftnaGGb/view?usp=sharing

And the HTML Given below (Note that these are all copied from the browser source.. In real these are all fetched from the SQL)

```
<form class="predictForm" name="predictForm" id="predictForm" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="form-group clearfix" data-question="1">
        <div class="inner-form-group predictType">
            <label>Match Winner</label>
            <select class="form-control match_winner" name="match_winner" id="match_winner">
                <option value=""> - Select Team - </option>
                <option value="4">team4</option>
                <option value="5">team5</option>
                <option value="6">team6</option>
                <option value="7">team7</option>
                <option value="8">team8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-form-group predictVal" style="display: block;">
            <label>Points</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control match_winner_val" name="match_winner_val" id="match_winner_val" placeholder="Value">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix" data-question="12">
        <div class="inner-form-group predictType">
            <label>Best Batsman</label>
            <select class="form-control best_batsman" name="best_batsman" id="best_batsman">
                <option value=""> - Select Player - </option>
                <option value="7" title="team6">Name 1</option>
                <option value="9" title="team5">Name 2</option>
                <option value="10" title="team5">Name 3</option>
                <option value="12" title="team8">Name 4</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-form-group predictVal" style="display: block;">
            <label>Points</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control best_batsman_val" name="best_batsman_val" id="best_batsman_val" placeholder="Value">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix" data-question="8">
        <div class="inner-form-group predictType">
            <label>Best catch done by</label>
            <select class="form-control best_catch_by" name="best_catch_by" id="best_catch_by">
                <option value=""> - Select Player - </option>
                <option value="3" title="team5">Name 1</option>
                <option value="7" title="team5">Name 2</option>
                <option value="8" title="team8">Name 3</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-form-group predictVal">
            <label>Points</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control best_catch_by_val" name="best_catch_by_val" id="best_catch_by_val" placeholder="Value">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix" data-question="4">
        <div class="inner-form-group predictType">
            <label>Runner Up Team</label>
            <select class="form-control runner_up_team" name="runner_up_team" id="runner_up_team">
                <option value=""> - Select Team - </option>
                <option value="4">team4</option>
                <option value="5">team5</option>
                <option value="6">team6</option>
                <option value="7">team7</option>
                <option value="8">team8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-form-group predictVal">
            <label>Points</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control runner_up_team_val" name="runner_up_team_val" id="runner_up_team_val" placeholder="Value">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix" data-question="5">
        <div class="inner-form-group predictType">
            <label>Max Six</label>
            <select class="form-control max_six" name="max_six" id="max_six">
                <option value=""> - Select Team - </option>
                <option value="4">team4</option>
                <option value="5">team5</option>
                <option value="6">team6</option>
                <option value="7">team7</option>
                <option value="8">team8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="inner-form-group predictVal">
            <label>Points</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control max_six_val" name="max_six_val" id="max_six_val" placeholder="Value">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group clearfix">
        <button type="submit">
            <span class="front">
                <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                <span class="value">Send <span>Predictions</span></span>
            </span>
            <span class="back">
                <i class="fas fa-paper-plane"></i>
                <span class="value">Send <span>Predictions</span></span>
            </span>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

In short, I need to insert the

1. Name, and value of the select field;
2. The value of the number Input (Without the field name)

into the database..

---

#### What I've tried so far..

1. I've tried to post all the values and split it into different arrays of four. But it didn't work as expected as the third element in the array is not needed, and due to some other reasons..
2. I made a hidden element in the html, which gets updated with the field name, and values with an array; With an on change function for both select, and number input. I then POST it along with other data. But it creates more bugs than the one we solves, as different users interact with the form in different ways.. (Note that None of the fields are required.. All of them are optional..)
3. I Googled my issue... Many many many times

```php
<?php
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if($value != "") {
            echo "<table>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $key;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $value;
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: phpmyadmin is just an interface for you to interact with the db. thats all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sending the Form content to php and need to get the Values of your inputs, they are all present in the $_POST array.

every input (also selects) are present with its html-name attribute.

for your Form-Element "runner_up_team" you could access it like this:

```
$val = $_POST["runner_up_team"]; // $val contains the seleceted value from the html-select
```

So if you want to get the number for a selected field i would suggest to use something like this:

```
$result = new array();
foreach ($_POST as $inputName => $value) {
   // We only want to inspect the selects and retrieve the number value later.
   if (strpos($inputName, '_val') === FALSE) {
     if ($value != '') {
       // With the current select name + the suffix we get the name for the number input field
       $numberInputName = $inputName . '_val'; 

       // Now we can access the value of the number input with the name.
       $numberInput = $_POST[$numberInputName];

       // now you can put your data into a result array.
       $result[$value] = $numberInput;
     }
   }
}
```

The result array should now look like this:

```
["runner_up_team" => 43, "max_six" => 32]
```

If you now want to access it in a loop, you can use your previous example, but use the resultarray:

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    if($value != "") {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
    }
}
?>
```

---

**UPDATE** 
For your question in the comment:

replace following line

```
$result[$value] = $numberInput;
```

with

```
$element = new array();
$element['select_name'] = $inputName;
$element['number'] = $numberInput;
$element['select_value'] = $value;
$result[] = $element;
```

This will change the second foreach to:

```
<?php
foreach ($result as $value) {
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value['select_name'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value['select_value'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value['number'];
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot .. This was exactly what I wanted..

In addition to this, is there any way to get the name of the select field too? Since all the name attributes are coming from DB, It's impossible to hardcode it in PHP.

So when I get these 2 values in the PHP, I need to know which question does this answer belong to... For that, I need to get the name attribute of the select field (Which comes from SQL, and it might change every time depending on the admin using the app)

Comment: I updated my answer to answer this question as well. If this is the answer which solves your question, pls mark it as Valid answer, or upvote. Thx a lot.

Comment: That solved my problem.. Thanks a lot, I was trying to do it for the past 2 days.. :)